# Issue in ie 11 with placeholder Angular 5

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

There is following condition in our project

```
 isSearchFocused ? 'Type two or more characters' : 'Search markets'
```

in html

```
  <input class="market-search__search-input"
  type="text"
  #marketSearchInput
  (click)="handleSearchClick()"
   placeholder="{{ isSearchFocused ? 'Type two or more characters' : 'Search markets' }}"
  formControlName="query">
```

Method 'handleSearchClick'

```
handleSearchClick() {
this.isSearchFocused = true;
this.marketSearchInput.nativeElement.focus();

if (!this.active) {
  this.openModal();
}
```

}

When value 'isSearchFocused' change by event click from 'false' to 'true' - work fine in all browser except  IE 11.In IE 11  text change when input disappear focus.
Any ideas?

Comment: try [placeholder]

Comment: everything works same

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this using form group and custom label with some css style .

**Html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text"
      #marketSearchInput formControlName="market"
      (focus)="handleSearchClick()" (blur)="handleSearchBlur()">
    <span class="mask-placeholder" 
    *ngIf="this.myFormGroup.value['market'].length === 0">
    {{ isSearchFocused ? 'Type two or more characters' : 'Search markets' }}</span>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**Ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Simple form field */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-overview-example.css']
})
export class FormFieldOverviewExample {
  isSearchFocused: Boolean = false;
  myFormGroup: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.myFormGroup = new FormGroup({
      market: new FormControl('')});
  }
  handleSearchClick(){
    this.isSearchFocused = true;
  }

  handleSearchBlur(){
    this.isSearchFocused = false;
  }
}
```

**CSS/SCSS**

```
.mask-placeholder {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      color: #a9a9a9;
      font-weight: 100;
      top: 6px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

working [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stbx2w?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.html)